# $n$ times integrated Brownian motion martingale process

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240327/n-times-integrated-brownian-motion) post, we found that a $n$ times integrated Brownian motion could be expressed as,
\begin{align}
V_n(t) = \int_0^t V_{n-1}(s)\ ds = \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^t (t-s)^n\ dB_s,
\end{align}
where $V_1(t) = \int_0^t B_s\ ds$. Using the above result, I want to prove that the process
\begin{align}
M_n(t) = V_n(t) - \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{t^j}{j!\cdot (n-j)!} \int_0^t (-s)^{n-j}\ dB_s
\end{align}
is a martingale.

Therefore, I interpret $M_n(t) = f(t,B_t)$ as a function of $t, B_t$. Now, if 
\begin{align}
\int_0^T \mathbb{E}\big[f_{B_t}(t,B_t)^2\big] ds < \infty
\end{align}
and $f_t + \frac{1}{2}f_{B_t,B_t} = 0$ then $f(t,B_t)$ is an martingale on $[0,T]$.

Now, I am wondering how to differentiate
\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dt} V_n(t) = \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^t \frac{d}{dt}\big[(t-s)^n\ \big]dB_s \qquad \text{and} \\
&\frac{d}{dt} \bigg[ \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{t^j}{j!\cdot (n-j)!} \int_0^t (-s)^{n-j}\ dB_s \bigg],
\end{align}
since $t$ is in the integrand of the integral as well. Or should I try a whole different approach?

**Edit:**
\begin{align}
M_n(t) &= V_n(t) - \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{t^j}{j!\cdot (n-j)!} \int_0^t (-s)^{n-j}\ dB_s \\
&= \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^t (t-s)^n\ dB_s - \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{t^j}{j!\cdot (n-j)!} \int_0^t (-s)^{n-j}\ dB_s \\
&= \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^t \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j} t^j (-s)^{n-j} \ dB_s - \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{t^j}{j!\cdot (n-j)!} \int_0^t (-s)^{n-j}\ dB_s \\
&= \int_0^t \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{t^j}{j!\cdot (n-j)!} (-s)^{n-j}\ dB_s - \int_0^t \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{t^j}{j!\cdot (n-j)!}(-s)^{n-j}\ dB_s \\
&= \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^t (-s)^n\ dB_s.
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry but $M_n(t)=\int_0^t(-s)^ndB_s$, which is trivially a martingale, no?

Comment: $\frac{1}{n!}$ in front of the integral, isn't it? For me it is not directly clear why $M_n(t)$ is indeed a integral? Do you find a function $f(t,B_t)$ such that $f_t + \frac{1}{2}f_{B_t,B_t}=0$? Or do you find a function $f(B_t)$ such that ... ? I don't know.

Comment: Could you be explicit and explain if the question is why $\int_0^t(-s)^ndB_s$ is a martingale or what?

Comment: Can you explain why it is trivial that $\int_0^t (-s)^n\ dB_s$ is a martingale?

Comment: Well, say, because $\int_0^tu(s)dB_s$ with $u$ deterministic is one of the simplest examples of martingale for the Brownian filtration.

Comment: Okay, merci. What is the criterion for an integral like $\int_0^t u(s) dB_s$ with $u$ deterministic to be a martingale? To check if something is a martingale, I am still focussed on the property of conditional expectation, $\mathbb{E}[M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = M_s$ for all $s<t$.

Comment: ?? What is the textbook you are following? You might want to check their section "First examples of Brownian martingales".

Comment: Basics of Stochastic Analysis by Timo Seppäläinen, which is most of the time too complex. Although, I will take a look!